# Exchange Transport Agent. Forward email but don't deliver to addressed recipient

Tags: c#, email, exchange-server, agent, transport

I have created a transport agent which will check incoming email. If it is from a particular email address and to a particular recipient I want to forward the email to a separate mailbox (new RoutingAddress(rule.Last())) and block delivery to the intended recipient, but not remove their email address from the headers.

I am able to add a recipient which satisfies forwarding the email but can't find documentation regarding not delivering to a mailbox without removing the address from the header. Is this possible?

```
private void MyEndOfDataHandler(ReceiveMessageEventSource source, EndOfDataEventArgs e)
    {
        var allRcpts = e.MailItem.Recipients.GetEnumerator();

        //conditions
        while (allRcpts.MoveNext())
        {
            foreach (var rule in rules)
            {
                if (rule.First().Equals(allRcpts.Current.Address.ToString(), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    //skip first and last email addresses
                    for (int i = 1; i < (rule.Count()-1); i++)
                    {
                        if (rule[i].Equals(e.MailItem.FromAddress.ToString(), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                        {
                            e.MailItem.Recipients.Add(new RoutingAddress(rule.Last()));
                            goto ruleapplied;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ruleapplied: ;  //rule applied, do nothing else, exit agent
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> > e.MailItem.Recipients

Are the envelope (or P1) headers of the Messages you need to understand the difference between the envelope headers and the Message headers (P2) http://www.websense.com/support/article/t-kbarticle/What-are-P1-and-P2-headers-in-SMTP. But the Envelope headers are what controls the routing and delivery of the Messages so adding or removing address at this level does not modify the Message headers (which is what the user can see). So what you want to do is remove the Address you don't want the message delivery to from the envelope headers.

Cheers
Glen

Comment: Thanks Glen - `e.MailItem.Recipients.Remove(allRcpts.current);` has done the trick.